How to use Vuetify v-dialog isActive to load a function everytime it is changed to true
I am trying to make my components a little more compact and modular and that means encapsulating a v-dialog component and its internal items. This v-dialog is activated from the parent component with the click event as shown:
        <v-menu location="bottom">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-btn class="mx-3" icon="mdi-dots-horizontal" size="small" color="primary" v-bind="props" variant="tonal"/>
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item link>
              <v-list-item-title>Draft Acknowledgement Email</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item link>
              <v-list-item-title>Process Upload
                <EmailFilesAssignment :emails="selectedEmails" :mailbox="activeMailboxLabel"/>
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu> 

Then the component is as follows:
<template>
  <v-dialog activator="parent" max-width="800">
    <template v-slot:default="{ isActive }">
      <v-card rounded="lg">
        <v-card-title class="d-flex justify-space-between align-center">
          <div class="text-h5 text-medium-emphasis ps-2">
            Assign Files For Upload
          </div>

          <v-btn
            icon="mdi-close"
            variant="text"
            @click="isActive.value = false"
          ></v-btn>
        </v-card-title>


        <v-card-actions class="my-2 d-flex justify-end">
          <v-btn
            class="text-none"
            rounded="xl"
            text="Cancel"
            @click="isActive.value = false"
          ></v-btn>

          <v-btn
            class="text-none px-5 mx-3"
            color="primary"
            rounded="xl"
            text="Begin Upload Process"
            variant="flat"
            @click="isActive.value = false"
          ></v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </template>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

The issue is I have some functions in my child component such as loadData() that is run when the child component is registered so it only runs once and actually seems to run when the v-menu is activated not when the v-dialog is activated. I need to tap into isActivated to run loadData() when this becomes true so I get a fresh reload every time as additional stuff is into the child component from this.

a watcher is needed which can run code any time isActive changes.

A watcher on isActive despite it is a slot? How would I do that?

didn't notice that!  in that case, you can always listen to the v-dialog update:modelValue event. The event emits a boolean for whether the dialog has just been opened or closed.

Could you post an example of this? I think that could be a good option and might fit what I need.

answer posted, hopefully it helps

Listen for update:modelValue event that is emitted from v-dialog whenever it opens or closes. The event parameter is a boolean with the status of the dialog (true if opened, false if closed).  Simplified version:
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-btn>
      Parent Activator
      <v-dialog
        activator="parent"
        @update:model-value="dialogUpdate"
      >
        <template v-slot:default="{ isActive }">
          <v-card text="test" title="Title">
            <template v-slot:actions>
              <v-btn
                text="Close"
                @click="isActive.value = false"
              ></v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-card>
        </template>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-btn>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup>
  const emit = defineEmits(['dialogOpened'])

  function dialogUpdate(isOpen) {
    if (isOpen) {
      console.log('dialog is open')
      // if need to know in parent
      emit('dialogOpened')
    }
  }
</script>

Vuetify Playground example

I have never used events created by a vuetify component so this is neat. THank you for this!!
